# What does the value of the gradient during NN training signify?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

The by default value for the gradient descent approach is 1e-5.

Is this a very small value for generalization to a testing set? What range should I keep it in?

Does the gradient signify the error between the targets and the predicted class during TRAINING (i.e using the training data)?

Comment: This belongs to Cross-Validated: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Answering your question, it is simply a training quickness (during the gradient descent), that is taking larger numbers will make training quicker but could result in non-optimal solutions, while smaller numbers train slow but give better answers. There is no silver bullet, just try to tweak it and see what works for you.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a "default value for the gradient descent approach". The gradient is the derivative of the error in terms of the loss function. You might be thinking of the learning rate.

Comment: @larsmans I think the OP is referring to the minimum gradient used as a stopping condition. For instance, the default value for min_grad in the Matlab NN toolbox is 1e-5: http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/traingd.html

Comment: @beaker: good point, 1e-5 is extremely small for a learning rate.

Comment: Yes, so sorry I'll repost my question there. Though I think I have my problem solved. I should have been more specific-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using regularization, you should check several values for the learning rate and several values for the number of iterations. You should do this on on a hold out set (also called validation set). If you're using regularization you should not do this and instead try several values for the weight of the regularization term (usually C or lambda).

As for values people try from 2^-10 to 2^-1. Also it is in general useful if your feature values are in a reasonable numerical range (from -1 to 1) or from (0 to 1).